# Fit zoomed image to window with OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, zooming

I am using OpenCV (3.3) with the Qt Backend as I want to use the integrated zoom functionality. Now I want to achieve that the zoomed image is fitted to the full window. At the moment the zoomed image is only shown in the area where the initial image was shown which is not optimal, at least when I use vertical images.

What is the best way to do this?

**EDIT**
Example picture:

[Full view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYYOr.jpg)

[zoomed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGUL1.jpg)

In comparison to that the behavior of the standard Xubuntu image viewer. This is the behavior I want to achieve with OpenCV. The zoomed image fills the full window.

[Full view image viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lBYU.png)

[zoomed view image viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8BmF.jpg)

---

```
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int annotate(string imageFilePath) {

    Mat img = imread(imageFilePath); 
    if (img.empty()) {
        cout << "Error loading image " << imageFilePath << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    namedWindow("AnnotationTool", cv::WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL);
    imshow("AnnotationTool", img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <pathToImage>" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    string pathToImage = argv[1];
    annotate(pathToImage);
}
```

Comment: If you show some example picture...

Comment: @AlexanderVX I added an example picture to the original post.

Comment: It seems to me that zoomed is already fit in? It is not properly centered?

Comment: Yes, centering is not the problem. I would like to fill the space beside the zoomed image.  If it's not clear, I'll provide an additional image.

Comment: An additional image is needed.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguities. Hopefully it will be clear with the additional images.

Comment: I see, and to fix it your code is needed.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I added a minimal code example now.

Comment: Either I have to write quite a few lines of code to make own image window with Qt which I can but why, or you can try to apply  `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` instead of `WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL`.

Comment: With CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE I cannot resize the window so that it is not possible to view the full image.

Comment: Try http://answers.opencv.org/question/84985/resizing-the-output-window-of-imshow-function/. It is not very flexible to use OpenCV own window but developing a new one is quite a bit of work. I develop own QML item types that render from OpenCV cv::Mat. But that is some work already.

Comment: @AlexanderVX The solution given in your URL does not solve my issue.

Comment: You need to write own graphcis renderer then.

Comment: Well, thanks for your effort. I'll spend time on it if it is worth it.